# Failing creating a txt file with subfolders in Android

Tags: android, file

Fellow programmers.
Cuold you possibly take a look on this simple code frag and tell me what's wrong here?

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/asteroids/modules"); 
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/asteroids/modules/" + fileName);             
if (!file.exists()) {     
    dir.mkdir();
    file.createNewFile();              
}
```

I keep geting `ENOENT (No such file or directory)` on `file.createNewFile();`

I just want to create a simple txt file nested in 2 subfolders on my SDcard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely scenario is that the `asteroids` directory doesn't exist, so you can't create the `modules` directory within it.

Use `dir.mkdirs()` to ensure that all parent directories also get created.